# How to run a js function stored in a cookie

Tags: javascript, function, cookies

I have a section on a website that has multiple pages which are accesed with ajax. I'd like to run a js function that is stored in a cookie so that i can refresh the content of my page after doing some modifications from several select boxes and remain on the same page(in the cookie i stored a function with pagination information and also the month and year selected that looks like this "pontaje(2,1,7,2015)").
The cookie name is "pagina". 
So i'd like to run the function that is stored in the cookie.
I think it should look something like:

```
        var pagina = getCookie("pagina");

        new pagina;
```

I get this error in the console:Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

The practical result that i need is "new pontaje(2,1,7,2015);"

Could you please help making this work?

Comment: There's always `eval`, but Ew. Why not just store the data?

Comment: Do not do this. If you can access your cookie via JavaScript, so can other JavaScript programs. Anyone could change the contents of that cookie and insert arbitrary JavaScript, which you then `eval()`. Oops.

Comment: Aunt Bee I got a cooking tip for you: DON'T

Comment: I smell a XY problem.

Comment: This is an outstandingly bad idea as it will generate a bunch of security issues, you most certainly do not want to blindly execute anything that originated from users. People can and *will* do malicious things here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, i don't think that the right solution here is to store the function in the cookies, instead - store the values and send them to the function .

if you really want to run a javascript code which is in string mode, retrieved from the cookie, you could use :

1. eval
2. setTimeout (javascriptString, milliSeconds)

but you should consider security as this code comes from the client side and you are not really controls its value .

Comment: thank all of you for your comments and answers. i stored the values and used them like this: var paginaPTrepartizare=getCookie("paginaPTrepartizare");

 var res = paginaPTrepartizare.split(",");   

new pontaje(res[0],res[1],res[2],res[3]);  the cookie having this value: 2,1,7,2015

Answer (score 0):

You can eval() it, but it's a very bad idea, and with a big security hole.

```
var pagina = getCookie("pagina");
eval("new "+pagina);
```

You must to rethink your code or your workflow, it is very very bad idea.